# "For" loop does not delete all charts in Worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet on which I create 9 new charts and they are named Chart67 to Chart 75 because there are 66 other charts that are fixed. But before creating the charts, I'd like to delete them if for whatever reason they might exist on the sheet.

The code below does not do the job and deletes only a set of the charts (67, 69, 71, 73 & 75) and then gives an error "Method 'ChartObjects' of object '_Worksheet' failed". Everytime I start the code it deletes further charts but again not all and again gives the same error.

But if I test the code by simply commenting out the ".delete" line, then I get in the debug window all the charts I intend to delete without any error.

Can anyone explain to me what is happening? I also debugged step by step and I see that when the delete function is in place, the screen flickers and then selection simply jumps a charts.

(before i posted the question, I tested one more thing, and to me it looks like the For loop remembers the first value (67) and since it does not exist anymore it jumps over 68 and so on) -> but why? How should I proceed?

Thx

```
Public Sub test()
Dim wsCR As Worksheet:     Set wsCR = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Charts")
Dim i As Long

For i = 67 To wsCR.ChartObjects.count
    wsCR.ChartObjects(i).Activate
        With ActiveChart
            Debug.Print .Parent.Name
            '.Parent.Delete
        End With
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

**First Loop:** When `i = 67`, you will delete chart 67.
**A Shift Occurs:** Now your chart names will shift accordingly. `68 goes to 67`. `69 goes to 68`. etc.
**Next Loop:** Now you are on `i = 68`. But notice that your chart 68 now has a corresponding value of 67. The chart to be deleted will be the **new** chart associated with `i = 68`, which was really chart #69 when you originally started your loop (68 will get skipped which is consistent with the results you described).

This is why every other chart is being deleted.

You can try going backwards to address this problem since nothing will shift with the deletion:

```
For i = wsCR.ChartObjects.count to 67 Step - 1
    wsCR.ChartObjects(i).Delete
Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to do the `For Each` approach, this should probably work:

```
Sub trythis()
    Dim c As ChartObject, ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        For Each c In ws.ChartObjects
            If c.Index > 66 Then c.Delete

        Next c
    Next ws

End Sub
```